# Remove all query parameters except for one in page URL (Google Looker Studio)

Tags: looker-studio, google-analytics-4

I’m getting really turned around with this and could use some help.

I’m trying to create a calculated field in Google Looker Studio of the URL and the `slug` query parameter, excluding all other query parameters.

I’ve been able to exclude all URL parameters (`^[^?]+(\?.*)`) and extract the text of the slug query parameter (`^(?:.*)(?:\\?|&)slug=([^&]+)(?:.*)$`) but I can’t figure out how to meld this logic together and exclude all parameters except "?slug=". Does anyone have any ideas on how I could achieve this?

An example of what I’m trying to achieve:

Given URL: `https://www.testdomain.ca/ve/exhibit/?slug=mischief-and-mirth-ve&utm_source=Newsletter&utm_campaign=Issue+%23+1+-+December+10%2C+2021&utm_medium=email&fbclid=IwAR3nzUpFtDUhgiP107OMPaVAH6bATzau8ahm6h1qCGFqgQmNc4oy3_hvaDo_aem_Ac7lJjCjyx7rB-t_poeCB2_9_Em20sidNF53FpbCc3eixgSQfgc3wVfemHPcQ4wkv0g`

Desired result: `https://www.testdomain.ca/ve/exhibit/?slug=mischief-and-mirth-ve`

Answer (score 0):

*Can you try:*

```js
REGEXP_EXTRACT(URL,"[^&]*")
```

[image]